# How to resolve urls correctly in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have url for product details (domain.com/productdetail/1/name-of-product), When i click "about us" page while still in this url, I get an error "this url doesnt exist"(domain.com/productdetail/1/about-us). How can i get the url to resolve correctly to domain.com/about-us

This is my productDetail route

```
Route::get('/productDetail/{id}/{pro_name}', 
'HomeController@detailPro');
```

this is about-us route

```
Route::get('about-us', function(){
return View('about');
});
```

I would like to get the exactly route `(domain.com/about-us)` instead of it chaining at the end of the current url `(domain.com/productdetail/1/about-us)`.

Comment: Shouldn't matter but have you tried using `Route::get('/about-us' ...` ?

Comment: did try giving the link as `/about-us` instead of `about-us`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better to put routes as named routes.

```
Route::get('/productDetail/{id}/{pro_name}','HomeController@detailPro')->name('product.view');

Route::get('about-us', function(){
  return View('about');
})->name('about-us');
```

Call the specific route as

```
 <a href="{{route('about-us')}}">about us</a>
 <a href="{{route('product.view',['id' => $id, 'pro_name' => 'name_of_product'])}}">View Product</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using alias as @jitheshJose has answered would fix your issue, but i think your issue is as simple as this:

You're on the page "domain.com/productdetail/1/name-of-product" and you have a link with `href="about-us"`.

when this link is clicked, it will lead to "domain.com/productdetail/1/about-us".

to fix this, change the link in the href to `href="/about-us"`.

To understand better what's happening here, lookup the difference between relative link and absolute link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option you can use.

```
    Route::get('product-detail/{id}/{pro_name}', [
        'as' => 'product.view',
        'uses' => 'HomeController@detailPro',
    ]);

    Route::get('about-us', [
        'as' => 'about'
    ], function(){
          return View('about');
    });
```

Link:

```
 <a href="{{route('about')}}">About</a>
 <a href="{{route('product.view',['id' => $id, 'pro_name' => 'name_of_product'])}}">My Product</a>
```